# How to use PSR-4 in methods with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, psr-4

Excuse me guys I am trying to use PSR-4 into my PHP project until now I have only one problem; If I only use classes

```
<?php namespace backend\controllers;

    class Conexion
    {
        public function __construct() {

            echo "hi";
        }
    }
```

and after in other file I put this it works fine

```
<?php 
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use backend\controllers\Conexion as Conexion;

$user = new backend\controllers\Conexion;
```

but if I try to change in the first block code by this:

```
<?php namespace backend\controllers;

    class Conexion
    {
        public function __construct() {

           $conexion = new mysqli('localhost','mysql','root','');
           if($conexion) {
              echo "1";
           } else {
              echo "0";
           }
        }
    }
```

I get that following error

> Fatal error: Class 'backend\controllers\mysqli' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\master-pure-php\app\backend\controllers\DataBaseController.php
>   on line 9

But I need to use a named method inside a class but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not laravel specific why include laravel tag

Comment: Yeah you're so right excuse me I was very tired when I wrote this question

Answer (score 2):

As you can see - it's looking for mysqli under 'backend\controllers\mysqli'

A Quick fix...
Change

```
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','mysql','root','');
```

to

```
$conexion = new \mysqli('localhost','mysql','root','');
```

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful your answer

Comment: @Ing. Alfred Paz, My answer was a quick fix, Jack's answer is more appropriate. In any case you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli` class is defined in the global namespace; in order to use it you could put this in your source code (at the top of your script):

```
use mysqli;
```